# How to sync a repository with github?

Tags: github, version-control

I cloned a repository from GITHUB onto my local machine. And then I made a few direct commits to the GITHUB copy itself. Now I want to sync my local copy with the remote one. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code from the remote repository:

```
git pull origin master
```

To send code to the remote repository:

```
git push origin master
```

In both commands:

- `origin` is the remote (`git remote -v`)
- `master` is the remote branch to get/send code of/to

You may get some divergences between the local and the remote code.
Putting back the code back together is called a merge, sometimes it is done automatically (as often as possible) sometimes you will need to do it manually but this is another problem.